# iPhone UISlider to NSNumber

Tags: iphone, uislider

I'm trying to get the value of a UISlider and store it into part of a CoreData entity.

The score I need to save will either be the value of the slider (i.e. slider.value) or 10 minus the value of the slider (i.e. 10 - slider.value)

I'm trying to put it into an NSNumber and when I use the intValue it works fine.

When I use either...

```
score = [NSNumber numberWithInt:slider.value];
```

or...

```
score = [NSNumber numberWithInt:10 - slider.value];
```

it works perfectly and I can recall the values at a later date with no problems.

However, I really need to get the value to 1 decimal place but whenever I try this I just can't get it to work.

I really don't even know where to start.  I can NSLog the doubleValue out with no problems but I can't figure out how to get this into an NSNumber.

I seem to always get the error "Cannot convert to a pointer type (2)"

Any help is much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: "whenever I try this I just can't get it to work." --> What have you tried?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tried `numberWithFloat`:? If you're using an int, you will of course never get any decimal places because an integer by definition is a whole number.

Comment: LOL, I'm almost certain that I tried that.  Oh well, it's working now!  Thanks!

Will accept the answer in 5 mins (when timer runs out).

Answer (score 2):

If you can  NSLog the doubleValue out with no problems then the following method should work:

```
- (id)initWithDouble:(double)value
```

Comment: Thanks! This also worked but I have given the answer to Tom as his reply was first.

Thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

`UISlider -value`: is of type float, so `10 - slider.value` gives a float, and `numberWithInt:` is expecting an int (which *might* cast automatically), but as you want a float you should use `numberWithFloat:` anyway.

But your error "Cannot convert to a pointer type (2)" is not precision-related, it's more a pointer/value thing. Is score of type `NSNumber *`? Or is it just a plain float/double? What line gives this error? Maybe give some more code.

Comment: Thanks, I was trying to use NumberWithFloat:[slider.value floatValue]

This was causing the error.  Sorted now though :D

Thanks!